# Forwarding incoming email for a single email to two Internal emails and one external email

Tags: email, exchange, mail-forwarding

Alright here is the scenario, and I apologize if this was posted somewhere as I could not find in other forums, I have an email address lets call support@example.com.

The purpose of this email is so that our company can have our internal users send to this email and we would like it to go to two internal emails (internal help desk) and also one external email (external help desk).

We tried to do this as a distribution list but the problem is for the external help desk a ticket is automatically created in the system and will auto reply back which includes that distribution list so that created a horrible loop.

So I tried to also tried to switch to a mailbox to have it where it forwards to emails but the problem is the email never forwards external. I checked the queue and I do see it being blocked and I even checked to ensure that mailbox is allow to forward externally.

I also tried to mess with the Transport Rules but with a distribution list you can not do a forward and for a mailbox what happen was it never made it to the internal emails to where it follows my rules.

Does anyone have any advice or can link me to somewhere to help me on this? I am about ready to look at a third party program to get this resolve but would like to accomplish via Exchange. FYI this is an Exchange 2013.

Comment: `We tried to do this as a distribution list but the problem is for the external help desk a ticket is automatically created in the system and will auto reply back which includes that distribution list so that created a horrible loop` - How did you determine that? Exchange should have prevented a loop from occurring.

Comment: `So I tried to also tried to switch to a mailbox to have it where it forwards to emails but the problem is the email never forwards external. I checked the queue and I do see it being blocked and I even checked to ensure that mailbox is allow to forward externally` - None of that makes any sense to me. Can you clarify that?

Comment: Let me clarify. 1. The reason is because What happens is email comes to the Distribution list. The email will forward to the external email (ticketing system) and then to the two internal emails. The ticketing system will then reply back which includes the distribution list which then goes back to the two internal emails and the external email which then opens another ticket. 2. By that I made an email account within Exchange and added Mailbox Rules to forward to the two internal emails and the one external email but the external email never receives the email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said you tried transport rules. Did you try making a rule in there that would block the external helpdesk address from sending mail to the distro group instead or trying to do forwarding rules with it? Also some helpdesk systems allow you to create filters for emails so it wouldn't automatically generated a ticket to the sender. So perhaps you can look into that as well.

Comment: I just tried that now and you are not able to add distribution groups. I get _SentTo predicate does not allow distribution groups. 'username'._ Also they reached out to the ticketing system and they are unable to add any filters.

Comment: I think I didn't write it correctly. Don't use the distro group as part of the rule. Instead use the external address in the rule. The external address is mailbox not a distro group right? And since it's external exchange shouldn't recognize it as a distro group. Or perhaps you need to let it receive emails from it but just not to that distro group?

Comment: Another possibility is bit more messy but you can replace the distro group with a regular mailbox and forward its emails to both internal/external addresses. Then the transport rule should let you block emails to that regular mailbox from the external one.

Comment: Okay after some more googling and a review to go over the steps again. I used what you mentioned about the Mailbox with the forwards. The issue with that was the forward was disabled. So I had to enable it using _Set-RemoteDomain_ . Here is a link I used from Microsoft [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997857%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx